# Weird behaviour when compiling CppUTest tests for application using Qt and Boost

Tags: c++, qt, boost, cpputest

I've following problem. When I try to compile .so library everything works fine.

```
Scanning dependencies of target logger
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/logger.dir/src/defaultconfig.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/logger.dir/src/loggerstate.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/logger.dir/src/configmanager.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/logger.dir/src/configuration.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/logger.dir/src/formatter.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/logger.dir/src/levelmap.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/logger.dir/src/logger.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/logger.dir/src/logworker.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library liblogger.so
[100%] Built target logger
```

By when I try to create executable which use for example `logger.cpp` eg. test file I get wall of errors. [Full log is here](http://pastebin.com/AAbMTz6k). However the most funny thing that it compiles on ones developer computer. We check compiler version, cmake version and everything is the *same*. The cpputest version wasn't the same.

Maybe anyone of you have face such problem and know what we doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In file included from /opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:51:0,
                 from /opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qabstractanimation.h:45,
                 from /opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore/QtCore:4,
                 from /opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentDepends:2,
                 from /opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent:3,
                 from /tmp/Quantum/src/logger/include/logworker.h:5,
                 from /tmp/Quantum/src/logger/include/logger.h:5,
                 from /tmp/Quantum/src/logger/tests/logger_test.cpp:5:
/opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qlist.h: In member function ‘void QList<T>::node_construct(QList<T>::Node*, const T&)’:
/opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qlist.h:374:44: error: ‘n’ does not name a type
     else if (QTypeInfo<T>::isComplex) new (n) T(t);
                                            ^
```

The error looks like the `<new>` header hasn't been included. Check that there isn't another file called "new" somewhere in the include paths, and check that no other headers define a macro like `_NEW` or `_LIBCPP_NEW` which would prevent `<new>` from being included correctly.

You might need to compile one of the failing files with a flag such as `-save-temps` so you can examine the preprocessed output, to see which files are being included, and if their content is being included.

You should also tell CMake to be verbose, so it prints the full compiler commands. It's useless to hide the details of the compilation if the compilation is failing - you need to know what's happening!

Comment: I found out that the problem here is the version of cpputest framework. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Finally we beat that problem. The issue here was, as suggest @Jonathan Wakely, that `cpputest` defines macro `_NEW` which prevent `new` from being included correctly. To resolve the issue we reorder the includes to include all libs before including `cpputest` headers.

Comment: That is a bug in cpputest. The identifier `_NEW` is a [reserved name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/981959) so a library like cpputest must not use it.

Comment: I'll report this on theirs site.